# Use of Integration in proving the given relation with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{2022}$ $\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r}$ $\binom{2022}{r}$ as given;

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Prove that
$$
\sum_{r=1}^{2022}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r}\binom{2022}{r} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2022}
$$

I have been trying to prove this by using the expansion of $(1-x)^{2022}$ after which the use of integral is what i was advised on by a few, so i wanted to know how it can be implemented here in the further continuation of the expansion

Comment: What have you tried? IE Did you take the steps that you listed out? If so, can you show your work and state what issues you've run into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $N\ge 0$ and define $\displaystyle F_N(x) = \sum_{r = 1}^{N}\frac{x^{r - 1}}{r}\binom{N}{r}$. Then your question concerns the value $F_{2022}(-1)$. We have
$$
(F_N(x) x)' = \sum_{r = 1}^N x^{r - 1}\binom{N}{r} = \frac{(x + 1)^{N} - 1}{x}.
$$
Notice that
$$
\int \frac{(x + 1)^{n + 1} - 1}{x}\, dx - \int \frac{(x + 1)^{n} - 1}{x}\, dx = \int (x + 1)^ndx;
\\
\int_{-1}^0 \frac{(x + 1)^{n + 1} - 1}{x}\, dx - \int_{-1}^0 \frac{(x + 1)^{n} - 1}{x}\, dx = \int_{-1}^0 (x + 1)^ndx = \frac{1}{n + 1}.
$$
Inducting on the last line we get
$$
\int_{-1}^0 \frac{(x + 1)^{n} - 1}{x}\, dx = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{r = 1}^n\frac{1}{r}.
$$
Consequently
$$
F_N(-1) = \int_{-1}^0(F_N(x)x)'dx = \int_{-1}^0 \frac{(x + 1)^{N} - 1}{x}\, dx = \sum_{r = 1}^N\frac{1}{r}.
$$